# Generating Numbers while adding zeros infront

Tags: javascript

I am trying to generate a function that generates sequence of numbers and add 0 accordingly to its front. However, it's not outputting the right numbers:

```
const generatingNumber = (start, end) => {

     let result = [];
     let output = '';

    for(let num = start; num <= end; num++){
       if(num.toString().length === 1){
          output = '000' + num.toString();
          result.push(parseInt(output));
       } else if (num.toString().length === 2){
         output = '00' + num.toString();
         result.push(parseInt(output));
       } else if (num.toString() === 3){
         output = '0' + num.toString();
         result.push(parseInt(output));
       } 


      result.push(num);


    }


  return result.join('\n');

};


console.log(generatingNumber(1, 3000));
```

Any idea what am I missing here why its not adding zeros?

Also is there a more succint way to do this?

Comment: You convert `output` to `int` again with `parseInt(output)`. So it will remove `0` from the front.

Comment: `parseInt('0001')` will result in `1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this something you want

```js
const generatingNumber = (start, end) => {

  let result = [];
  let output = '';

  for (let num = start; num <= end; num++) {
    if (num.toString().length === 1) {
      output = '000' + num.toString();
      result.push(output);
    } else if (num.toString().length === 2) {
      output = '00' + num.toString();
      result.push(output);
    } else if (num.toString().length === 3) {
      output = '0' + num.toString();
      result.push(output);
    } else {
      result.push(num);
    }
  }


  return result.join('\n');

};


console.log(generatingNumber(1, 3000));
```

`parseInt('0001')` will result in `1`. `parseInt` will remove all the 0's before of actual number because 0001 & 1 is same in integer.

So you have to push only string in result.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`padStart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) method.

> The **padStart()** method pads the current string with another string (multiple times, if needed) until the resulting string reaches the given length. The padding is applied from the start of the current string.

```js
const generatingNumber = (start, end) => {
  let result = [];
  let output = '';
  for (let num = start; num <= end; num++) {
    result.push(num.toString().padStart(4, 0));
  }
  return result.join('\n');
};

console.log(generatingNumber(1, 10));
```

Answer (score 0):

[parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) Removes all the leading zeros from the string before parsing it. You can change

```
output = '0' + num.toString();
result.push(parseInt(output));
```

to

```
output = '0' + num.toString();
result.push(output);
```

and all other similar states where you push to result array.

It will be storing strings but you cant store numbers with leading zeros.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is not to modify the **value**, but the **presentation** of the value instead.

There's no numerical difference between "00000000" and "0"; both are still the value 0. So if your value is converted to a `number` type, you'll not be able to show those leading zeroes.

This is the line where you're converting the digits to a numeric value

> ```
>       result.push(parseInt(output));
> ```

If you want to preserve the leading zeroes in your output, do **not** convert it to number; keep it as a string.

Also, instead of having those manual ifs depending on the length, take a look at the [padStart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) method. It can "fill" those zeroes at the front for however many digits you want, not just 4.

Answer (score 0):

A generic way of doing that without bounds to specific length or range, using [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from), [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), and [`padStart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart):

```js
const generatingNumber = (start, end) => {
  const range = end - start + 1;
  const maxLen = ('' + end).length;
  return Array.from({length: range}).map((_, i) => 
     (i + start).toString().padStart(maxLen, '0'));
};
console.log(generatingNumber(5, 3000).join('\n'));
```